# Building Single Codepipeline for Multiple Environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

We are trying to build an Application that uses Micro-frontends with React and Serverless architecture for our NodeJS backend. We are using AWS to deploy all our code. Since we'll be having multiple code repos and branches we had to build multiple Codepipelines to deploy the code. We are thinking of having two pipelines one for the frontend which takes the code from Github builds it and deploys it to AWS S3 bucket and the other for a backend which deploys the code to AWS Lambda functions. Is there a way where we can specify the AWS resources to where the code has to be deployed in a .yaml or JSON file and AWS Codepipeline will dynamically do the deployments into respective AWS Services?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look @ CloudFormation actions in CodePipeline and use CloudFormation actions.  You can config the info you're trying to config using a JSON file as a configuration to the CloudFormation action.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html

Comment: Can you pls share any documentation if you have one?

Comment: added link in answer